# Overlaying short video files on Linux? (ffmpeg)

Tags: merge, ffmpeg, video-processing

Does `ffmpeg` or any other tool support merging/overlaying (not concatenating) of video files?

I am trying to avoid frame-by-frame image merge into final video.

Answer (score 0):

I use melt for this, awesome tool:

http://www.mltframework.org/twiki/bin/view/MLT/